# One XMPP connection for more than one GCM/FCM app

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, xmpp, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a bunch of `FCM` projects and I'd like to use the same XMPP connection to send messages for all those projects. The `FCM` [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server#implementing-the-xmpp-connection-server-protocol) say that each connection needs to authenticate with the app id and server key, meaning I can use one XMPP connection for one project only. Is there any way around this?

Comment: I see. You should edit your post to mention that. I thought you were simply using a single project for FCM for all of your apps (which is also advisable). Anyways, I've been thinking about it and I'm not sure there is a workaround other than making use of just a single project

Comment: I'm sorry about the confusion, by app I mean FCM project. As far as I can see, that seems to be the only way too.

Comment: Yep. I'll edit and undelete my answer for visibility. However, if I find something, I'll be sure to update here. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the question is here. Just use the corresponding Sender ID and Server Key from your Firebase Project. However, do note of the connection limitation mentioned in the docs you linked:

> For each sender ID, FCM allows 1000 connections in parallel.

I don't really see any issue here, so long as you're using the same Firebase Project for FCM on all of your apps, you're good to go.

Unfortunately, if you have multiple projects, the only workaround I can only see that you can do is for you to use only a single project for your FCM processes.

Comment: My question is to be able to use more than one FCM projects over one XMPP connection.